# How do I map Freebase topic ids to the corresponding topic names?

Tags: api, freebase, youtube-analytics-api

I am using Youtube Analytics API. In the response I get the topics of channel as Freebase TopicIds. Since the Freebase API is deprecated now, how can I get the topic names to corresponding ids? I had a look at the Google Graph Search API (mentioned as an alternative to freebase api).

https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/#typical_use_cases.

But I am not sure if we can get topic names from topic ids using this API.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ids` parameter with the Knowledge Graph API Search API. https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/